# Post commit step in xCode

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4

Is there a way to make a post commit (to git) step in xCode 4?
I need this to call a step that will ssh the server and make a pull to automatically get files on server. A button that will automatically copy files I selected to a server via ssh/scp/sftp/ftp will be good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using a "classic" post-commit git hook? > [githook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)

Xcode or not, this is `git`, and calling a script on commit doing `rsync`, `git push` or whatever is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode doesn't have this functinality. File a request at bugreporter.apple.com. For now, third-party tools or the command line are your only options.